# How to increment the version number of an Ionic 3 project?

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a quick and easy way to increment the version number of an Ionic 3 project without having to manually edit each file where the version number appears?

I am thinking of `config.xml`, `package.json`, `src/index.html` and every other place inside the project where the version number appears.

Say I want to increment the version number from 2.3.4 to 2.3.5 after I've made some updates to the code. I would love to have something like

```
$ ionic run version-increment [major][middle][minor]
```

which would edit all the files at once.

Is there a plugin or a magic trick that could do that for me?

Comment: which Ionic version are you using? if Ionic 4 I might have a solution for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should tie version updates to your build process. This way when you initiate build process you auto-increment version of your app.

You could do it this way in Ionic 4:

**Step 1: Update ionic.config.json to feature a pre-build hook:**

```
{
  "name": "morphistic-app",
  "type": "angular",
  "id": "b8d9b232",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "hooks": {
    "build:before": "./config/build-before.js"
  }
}
```

**Step 2: Create build-before.js and add the following:**

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (ctx) => {

    if (ctx.build && ctx.build.configuration && ctx.build.configuration === "production") {

        console.log("production build: performing version bump...");

        // update package.json:
        let packageJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf-8').toString());
        let versionArray = packageJSON.version.split(".");
        versionArray[2] = (parseInt(versionArray[2])+1).toString();
        packageJSON.version = versionArray.join(".");
        fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, "\t"), 'utf-8');
        console.log("package.json app version updated");

        let prodEnvData = fs.readFileSync(`src/environments/environment.prod.ts`, 'utf-8');
        prodEnvData = prodEnvData.replace(/CURRENT_VERSION: ".*"/, `CURRENT_VERSION: "${packageJSON.version}"`);
        fs.writeFileSync('src/environments/environment.prod.ts', prodEnvData, 'utf-8');
        console.log("environments.prod.ts app version updated");

        let devEnvData = fs.readFileSync(`src/environments/environment.dev.ts`, 'utf-8');
        devEnvData = devEnvData.replace(/CURRENT_VERSION: ".*"/, `CURRENT_VERSION: "${packageJSON.version}"`);
        fs.writeFileSync('src/environments/environment.dev.ts', devEnvData, 'utf-8');
        console.log("environments.dev.ts app version updated");

        let localEnvData = fs.readFileSync(`src/environments/environment.local.ts`, 'utf-8');
        localEnvData = localEnvData.replace(/CURRENT_VERSION: ".*"/, `CURRENT_VERSION: "${packageJSON.version}"`);
        fs.writeFileSync('src/environments/environment.local.ts', localEnvData, 'utf-8');
        console.log("environments.local.ts app version updated");

        let defaultEnvData = fs.readFileSync(`src/environments/environment.ts`, 'utf-8');
        defaultEnvData = defaultEnvData.replace(/CURRENT_VERSION: ".*"/, `CURRENT_VERSION: "${packageJSON.version}"`);
        fs.writeFileSync('src/environments/environment.ts', defaultEnvData, 'utf-8');
        console.log("environments.ts app version updated");

        let configXmlData = fs.readFileSync('config.xml', 'utf-8');
        configXmlData = configXmlData.replace(/id="com.yourapp.ionic" version=".*"/, `id="com.yourapp.ionic" version="${packageJSON.version}"`);
        fs.writeFileSync('config.xml', configXmlData,'utf-8');
        console.log("config.xml app version updated");

    };

};
```

The code above also handles environment file changes, you can skip that if it is not your goal.

if you need to update any html file - see above example with config.xml

Also the code above assumes your version is a semver compatible schema aka "n.n.n"

Alternatively in ionic 3 you could do:

**Step 1: update your 'scripts' property inside package.json to point at your built step script:**

```
"scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --non-interactive",
        "ionic:serve:before": "cross-env MY_ENV='dev' node ./config/env.config.js",
        "ionic:build:before": "cross-env MY_ENV='prod' node ./config/env.config.js",
    }
```

Please note I am using [cross-env library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to ensure environment variable can be available in the context of the script below:

**Step 2: create env.config.js file:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
function readWriteSync() {
    let env = process.env.MY_ENV || 'dev';
    console.log("updating configuration for: ", env);
    // read env data:
    let envData = fs.readFileSync(`config/environment.${env}.ts`, 'utf-8');
    // read data from package.json:
    let packageJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf-8').toString());
    let version;
    if (env === "prod") {
        let versionArray = packageJSON.version.split(".");
        versionArray[2] = (parseInt(versionArray[2])+1).toString();
        packageJSON.version = versionArray.join(".");
        // write to package.json:
        fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, "\t"), 'utf-8');
    };
    version = packageJSON.version;
    // replace env data:
    envData = envData.replace(/CURRENT_VERSION: ".*"/, `CURRENT_VERSION: "${version}"`);
    // write env data
    fs.writeFileSync('src/environments/environment.ts', envData, 'utf-8');
    // update config.xml:
    let configXmlData = fs.readFileSync('config.xml', 'utf-8');
    configXmlData = configXmlData.replace(/id="com.yourapp.ionic" version=".*"/, `id="com.yourapp.ionic" version="${version}"`);
    fs.writeFileSync('config.xml', configXmlData,'utf-8');

};
readWriteSync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a big Ionic/ Cordova Project and the only Place where you really need to have the version number is the `config.xml`. You should make your App to work with the number only there and then the manually change is not a big deal.